# Calling APNdroid from broadcast reciever force close

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to write an app that calls APNdroid from a broadcast receiver.
I have checked out the APNdroid project from "google code", added it to my project's "Build path"
and imported the necessary classes ("Constants' and "IActionService').
From my BroadCast receiver I am starting the activity like so:

```
Intent APNintent = new Intent(Constants.CHANGE_STATUS_REQUEST);
    int onState = Constants.STATE_ON;
    intent.putExtra(Constants.TARGET_MMS_STATE, onState);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.TARGET_APN_STATE, onState);
    context.startActivity(APNintent);
```

However, when I start my app, it gets "Force Closed".
Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?
Do I need to define something in the manifest file?

Thank you.

Comment: What does the logcat say?  Force Closes are caused by uncaught exceptions.  The stack trace of the exception is written to the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer looking for "how to call and activity from a broadcast receiver".
I turns out I am missing a flag that should be added when launching an activity from a broadcast receiver.
The missing flag is: "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK"
The code looks like this:

```
Intent APNintent = new Intent(Constants.CHANGE_STATUS_REQUEST);
int onState = Constants.STATE_ON;
intent.putExtra(Constants.TARGET_MMS_STATE, onState);
intent.putExtra(Constants.TARGET_APN_STATE, onState);
APNintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(APNintent);
```